# Ошибка доступа к членам класса С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> class Matrix
{
private:

    T** arr;
    int rows, cols;

public:
};

 template <typename T>
    T min(Matrix<T>& a)
    {
        T minimal = a.arr[0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.GetRows(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.GetCols(); j++)
            {
                if (a.arr[i][j] < a.arr[i][j + 1])
                {
                    if (j >= a.GetCols())
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    minimal = a.arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return minimal;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        Matrix<Fraction> a(2, 2);
        cout << "Enter 4 array elements of fractions:" << endl << "(sign, unit, num, denom)";
        cin >> a;
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << endl << min(a);
        return 0;
    }
```

Проблема такая: при вызове функции min() выводит ошибку (Matrix::arr: невозможно обратиться к private член(а конкретно к a.arr), объявленному в классе "Matrix")

Comment: ну так всё правильно, почему вдруг функция ```min()``` должна иметь доступ к приватным полям вашего класса ```Matrix```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо сделайте arr public, либо допишите публичный метод геттер, типа

```
T GetValueByIndex(const size_t i, const size_t j) const {
    ....
}
```